# How to move content to drupal 7 region?

Tags: drupal-7, region

I have created a region named "footer" in my drupal 7 template.
I have created a content type named "footer-article".
I have created a block called "footer-block".

What I want to do is:
whenever I create an article of "footer-article" content type
I want it to automatically reside in the "footer" region in all of my pages/ or some of the pages?
What is the most efficient and simplest way to do it?

because I was thinking that I always need to create new blocks and put article inside this block in order for me to position it in my desired region?

I am a newbie in drupal 7
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Install the views module. Always install the views module.

http://drupal.org/project/views

It will allow you to make a list of a content type, which you can then export as a block and add to your region. This will automatically update the block when ever you add a new "footer-article".

You can set the view to show full posts, teasers or certain fields.

It's the best module for Drupal in my opinion and is a must have for any Drupal sites.